# How can I get a specific day of the month in PHP from a number?

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

Basically, I have a date set to today. From that date, I want to get the next and previous 20th day of the month. Basically, starting with 07/10/2020 (date of the post in d/m/Y format), I should end up with a date/timestamp to 20/09/2020 (previous 20th) and 20/10/2020 (next 20th).

I tried a few things and ended up with:

```
$ld_next_str = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("20 day this month"));
$ld_next_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $ld_next_str);

$ld_prev_str = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("20 day last month"));
$ld_prev_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $ld_prev_str);
```

But turns out this : `"20 day this month"` just adds 20 days to the current day so right now (on the seventh) it returns the 27th.

Knowing this, I figured I could probably just do something like subtracting the current day to that date (27 - 7 = 20) but I feel like there's probably a simpler way to do it, using `strtotime` without any extra steps.

Thanks in advance!

PS : I know you can get some days using "first" / "second" / "third" etc... but (I think) it doesn't go any higher than "twelfth", because I tried "twentieth" and that didn't work...

Comment: If you're starting with 25/10/2020, you want 20/10/2020 and 20/11/2020…? What if you start with 20/10/2020?

Comment: Why not use get a date for this and last month and then set the day of month to 20 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the previous 20th is:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $month - (1 - floor($day / 20)), 20, $year))
```

The formula for the next 20th is:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $month + floor($day / 20), 20, $year))
```

As a demo:

```
for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    for ($day = 1; $day <= 30; $day += 5) {
        $prev = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month - (1 - floor($day / 20)), 20, 2020);
        $next = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month + floor($day / 20), 20, 2020);
        echo "$day/$month/2020: ", date('d/m/Y', $prev), ', ', date('d/m/Y', $next), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1/1/2020: 20/12/2019, 20/01/2020
6/1/2020: 20/12/2019, 20/01/2020
11/1/2020: 20/12/2019, 20/01/2020
16/1/2020: 20/12/2019, 20/01/2020
21/1/2020: 20/01/2020, 20/02/2020
26/1/2020: 20/01/2020, 20/02/2020
1/2/2020: 20/01/2020, 20/02/2020
6/2/2020: 20/01/2020, 20/02/2020
11/2/2020: 20/01/2020, 20/02/2020
16/2/2020: 20/01/2020, 20/02/2020
21/2/2020: 20/02/2020, 20/03/2020
...
```

Comment: The solution is very special for the 20th and unfortunately not usable for other days such as the 2nd.

Comment: @jspit True, you will need to find a formula that works for other dates. In fact, it's a bit undefined how this is supposed to behave when you're starting on the 20th… I'll leave that up to the reader to implement for their case specifically. But this illustrates a safe approach, something that `strtotime` et al can't really do.

Answer (score 0):

Here a better solution by using DateTime

```
$lastMonth = (new DateTime("last month"))->format("Y-m-20");
$thisMonth = (new DateTime("this month"))->format("Y-m-20");
$nextMonth = (new DateTime("next month"))->format("Y-m-20");
echo "$lastMonth - $thisMonth - $nextMonth";
```

Comment: "-1 month" calculations are never safe. If it's March 30th, you'll get March 1st, not the end of February. You cannot rely on this in any way.

Comment: indeed with the -1 month you right.
To fit he would need to set the actual date to 15 like:

`$dat = strtotime(date("Y/m/15", strtotime("2020/02/01")));

$lastM = date("20/m/Y", strtotime("-1 month", $dat));
$nextM = date("20/m/Y", strtotime("+1 month", $dat));`

Answer (score 0):

Solution with an external class (a DateTime extension) that supports the [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) syntax.

The string "0 0 20 * *" specifies the 20th of every month and every weekday at 00:00.
The nextCron() and previousCron() methods are used to determine the previous/next point in time based on a specific date.

```
$cronStr = "0 0 20 * *";  //every 20th 00:00

//source on https://github.com/jspit-de/dt
$next20 = dt::create('now')->nextCron($cronStr);
echo $next20;  //2020-10-20 00:00:00

$prev20 = dt::create('now')->previousCron($cronStr);
echo $prev20;  //2020-09-20 00:00:00
```

Outputs for the execution on October 8, 2020.